# Are LightGBM treating Pandas Categoricals based on name or cat_code value?

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data, lightgbm

LightGBM provides the option to handle categorical variables without the need to onehot-encode the dataset.

One way to make use of this feature (from the Python interface) is to specify the column-names of the categorical features as a list using the `categorical_feature`-argument.
This approach requires the categories to be encoded as integers.

But an alternative is to provide LightGBM with a Pandas DataFrame where the columns which are categorical in nature is set the be of the Categorical dtype, and LightGBM will figure out which columns to treat as categoricals.

*But the underlying interger codes used in categoricals are set by Pandas, and will likely not be consistent across Python sessions. **Will mixed-up cat_codes lead to LightGBM misinterpreting entries in the categoricals?***

By a Pandas categorical, I'm refering to a feature set as `df['Some_categorical_feature'] = df['Some_categorical_feature'].astype('category')`.

Comment: Wouldn't this entirely depend on your code? Are you ending sessions, and re-reading the dataset into Python via Pandas, and re-running LightGBM? In this case, yes, you would need to re-assign the column to be categorical.

Comment: Yes, I am ending sessions, re-reading data and re-casting as Categoricals. But since the categorical feature contains the mapping of the cat_codes to the feature names, I thought that LightGBM might be smart enough to handle the case where the cat_codes are permuted, and handle the categorical feature(s) based on the name that maps to the cat_codes... do you know it that's the case?

Answer (score 4):

Pandas assigns categorical codes by sorting the keys (categories) before assigning the codes, and LightGBM relies on Pandas to handle assigning the categoridcal codes correctly.
Introducing a previously unseen category will break the ordering of the categoricals, and thus shift the categorical codes.

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/2761#issuecomment-586722068

Code to demonstrate the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import pandas as pd
import lightgbm as lgb

X_train = pd.Series(['D', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'A'],
                    name='X', dtype='category').to_frame()
X_deploy = pd.Series(['B', 'E', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
                     name='X', dtype='category').to_frame()

X_train_transformed = lgb.basic._data_from_pandas(X_train, None, None, None)
X_deploy_transformed = lgb.basic._data_from_pandas(X_deploy, None, None, None)

print("X_train", X_train, sep=':\n', end='\n\n')
# X_train:
#    X
# 0  D
# 1  A
# 2  C
# 3  C
# 4  E
# 5  E
# 6  A

print("X_deploy", X_deploy, sep=':\n', end='\n\n')
# X_deploy:
#    X
# 0  B
# 1  E
# 2  A
# 3  C
# 4  D
# 5  E
# 6  F


print('X_train_transformed', X_train_transformed, sep=':\n', end='\n\n')
# X_train_transformed:
# (array([[2.],
#        [0.],
#        [1.],
#        [1.],
#        [3.],
#        [3.],
#        [0.]], dtype=float32), None, None, [['A', 'C', 'D', 'E']])

print('X_deploy_transformed', X_deploy_transformed, sep=':\n', end='\n\n')
# X_deploy_transformed:
# (array([[1.],
#        [4.],
#        [0.],
#        [2.],
#        [3.],
#        [4.],
#        [5.]], dtype=float32), None, None, [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']])

print('X_train LGB-transformed codes and original Series')
# X_train LGB-transformed codes and original Series

print(*list(zip(X_train_transformed[0], X_train.X.to_list())), sep='\n', end='\n\n')
# (array([2.], dtype=float32), 'D')
# (array([0.], dtype=float32), 'A')
# (array([1.], dtype=float32), 'C')
# (array([1.], dtype=float32), 'C')
# (array([3.], dtype=float32), 'E')
# (array([3.], dtype=float32), 'E')
# (array([0.], dtype=float32), 'A')

print('X_deploy LGB-transformed codes and original Series')
# X_deploy LGB-transformed codes and original Series

print(*list(zip(X_deploy_transformed[0], X_deploy.X.to_list())), sep='\n', end='\n\n')
# (array([1.], dtype=float32), 'B')
# (array([4.], dtype=float32), 'E')
# (array([0.], dtype=float32), 'A')
# (array([2.], dtype=float32), 'C')
# (array([3.], dtype=float32), 'D')
# (array([4.], dtype=float32), 'E')
# (array([5.], dtype=float32), 'F')
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe another answer to this question is misleading. LightGBM does exactly what you'd hope for behind the scenes. See this comment: https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/2826#issuecomment-591579444

Relevant quote:

> LightGBM will set old categorical codes from a training phase during a prediction one (if they differ)...So internally prediction data will have all original codes from the training dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the answer form AllanLRH.
My solutions has two :

1. directly use category feature ,and send them to lightgbm model . The lightgbm's predict method can process the category features ,and the result is right.

   ```
   feature_1=['a','a','a','b','c']
   data=pd.DataFrame({'f1':feature_1,'f2':[1,2,3,4,5]})
   data['f1']=data['f1'].astype('category')
   lightgbm.predict(data)
   ```
2. we can deal the category feature manual, I use python dict or database table to convert the category value to code.

   ```
    feature_1=['a','a','a','b','c']
    data=pd.DataFrame({'f1':feature_1,'f2':[1,2,3,4,5]})
    data['f1']=data['f1'].map({'a':1,'b':2,'c':3})
    lightgbm.predict(data)
   ```

The two solution has the same result ,and both results are right .
This quetions has puzzled me a long time,and related bugs cost me two days.
Now the question is solved.